# PHP include is not including an existing file

Tags: php, include

I have a strange problem. I cloned a project from a git repository and when I run the page it throws some notices that I don't have defined some constants. The problem is that include() function is not including the file with these constants without any notice about it. The file is existing but is not included.

The strange thing is that when I change something in the file (add an empty new line, comment, etc.) and save it, everything is alright.

Has anyone this experience and solution?

//EDIT:
I don't know what is unclear on my question, but ok. I have a file witch includes another one:

```
<?php

include __DIR__ . '/languages/slovak.php';

?>
```

In slovak.php are definitions (this not work):

```
<?php

define("YES", "Ano");
define("NO", "Nie");
// ... etc

?>
```

When I add a new line or comment before first define() and save the file everything is OK.

```
<?php

// new line
define("YES", "Ano");
define("NO", "Nie");
// ... etc

?>
```

Comment: Please post a relevant piece of your code, it will help us to solve your problem

Comment: After some modifications, the file attributes could change, eg. read rights. It can also be character encoding, and a lot more things. But if it is working, then what is the issue?

Comment: Without actual code, it's impossible to tell what's wrong. But you might want to try replacing `include` with `require` and see if it throws any errors.

Comment: >> But if it is working, then what is the issue?
Issue is that I had to debug it. It took me a time.

Comment: Do you use APC cache and if so is stat turned on?